# Elegant defensive checks for nested values

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have the following function where data may not exist during the many nested steps

to obtain data. To prevent errors, doing the checks as follows.

1. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Please note that Optional chaining is not an option due to the project structure

and difficulties in upgrades at this stage.

Something like this would have been cleaner but as said Optional chaining is not an option.

```
  let Component = configMap[environment][locale]
    ?.find(config => config['names']?.includes(id))?.config;
```

The logic is to search through the config map and select the Component if it exists within the `dev` key. Else use the Component within the `default` key.

Example of this configMap is mentioned below. Actual map is much larger and has more keys than just `dev`.

2. Also looking for feedback if I could write these `ifs` in a more cleaner way.

Appreciate any feedbacks. Thanks.

To note, this is a React project.

```
import { configMap } from '../maps';

const get = (locale, environment, id) => {

  if (!id) return <Fragment />; // id example: '1', '12', '34'

  let Component = configMap[environment][locale]
    && configMap[environment][locale]
    && configMap[environment][locale].find(config => config['names'] && config['names'].includes(id))
    && configMap[environment][locale].find(config => config['names'].includes(id)).config;

  if (!Component) {
    Component = configMap['default'][locale]
      && configMap['default'][locale]
      && configMap['default'][locale].find(config => config['names'] && config['names'].includes(id))
      && configMap['default'][locale].find(config => config['names'].includes(id)).config;
  }

  if (Component) {
    return <Component />
  }

  return <Fragment />;
}
```

Just for reference, the configMap will look like this.

```
export const configMap = {
  'dev': {
    'australia': [
      {
        names: ['12'],
        config: AndroneDesignComponent, // AndroneDesignComponent is a React component 
      },
      {
        names: ['34'],
        config: ShreadDesignComponent, // ShreadDesignComponent is a React component 
      },
    ],
  },
  'default': {
    'australia': [
      {
        names: ['1'],
        config: ThymeDesignComponent, // ThymeDesignComponent is a React component 
      },
      {
        names: ['12'],
        config: DefaultDesignComponent, // DefaultDesignComponent is a React component 
      },
      {
        names: ['34'],
        config: DefaultDesignComponent, // DefaultDesignComponent is a React component 
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to extract the checking and getting of the component to its own function, such as:

```
import { configMap } from '../maps';

const getComponentFromConfigMap = (env, locale, id) => {
  const actualEnv = Object.keys(configMap).includes(env) ? env : "default";
  const actualLocale = Object.keys(configMap[actualEnv]).includes(locale) ? locale :  null;
  
  if(!actualLocale) {
    return null;
  }
  
  const component = configMap[env][locale].find(config => config['names'] && config['names'].includes(id)) || { config: null }; // Get the correct component config, or assign a null value to it
  
  return component.config;
  
}

const get = (locale, environment, id) => {
  const Component = getComponentFromConfigMap(environment, locale, id); // This will contain the correct component or null, if no matching component was found
  if (Component) {
    return <Component />
  } else {
    return <Fragment />;
  }
}
```

One thing to also note is that checking for the `id`  in the `if (!id) return ...` statement might give unexpected results, if the `id` can be something that is falsy (e.g. if someone is trying to `get` with an id of 0).

Further, in the suggestion above, on line `const component = configMap[env][locale].find(config => config['names'] && config['names'].includes(id))` the `config['names'] &&` might not be needed, if the object is guaranteed to always have `names` (even if it's empty) as was the case in the example `configMap` provided.